# asp mvc Ajax.BeginForm return View or value, confused on return types

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

If the the user is not using javascript, I will refresh the view with a RedirectToAction after an IsAjaxRequest check. This works when I have a user contrl in the page and return partial view.

BUt when I just want to return a value, say int, and also still want to use RedirectToAction when not an ajax request, how do i set up the method in the controller?

public ActionResult...

```
(if ajax request) Return View (new{value=5})? 
(if not) redirecttoAction ("view");
```

not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the JsonResult.

```
if (IsAjaxRequest()) {
    return Json(new { value = 5 });
} else {
    return RedirectToAction("parentAction");
}
```

It will serialize the anonymous object in to a JSON result.  Or if you really want to just return an "int", which isn't really common AJAX you should use the `ContentResult`.

Comment: what do you mean by common AJAX?

Comment: Common AJAX is returned as either JSON or XML.  But if you just want to return an int such as "5" in your response (think opening notepad and just entering "5" and then saving) that can be done but it will require special handling in your AJAX response.  JSON will look like "{ value: 5 }"

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to redirect to the action that renders the parent view with appropriate route data (and perhaps using TempData) to get the updated information to the partial view.

```
     if (IsAjaxRequest())
     {
         return Content( "5" );
     }
     else
     {
         return RedirectToAction( "parentAction", new { id = ??, value = 5 } );
     }
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is with the first part, returning to the View with an int value for the field in question doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry -- missed your point.  If you just want to return an int, pass it back as a ContentResult.